# Azure Managed SQL Instance with Domain joined Web Server

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are looking to switch out a vm with sql and instead use Azure managed SQL and have our web servers connect to them
web servers are a VM in azure and are part of a domain

how can i have the web servers connect to the sql managed instance without having to enter the SA creds in the connection string we would like to use Active Directory or Active Directory Service Principal names but i cant seem to get it to work.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

SQL Managed Instance does not support AD authentication (NTLM or Kerberos), only SQL Auth and [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/aad-security-configure-tutorial#azure-ad-authentication).

If your web app is hosted in Azure, then you can use an AAD [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) (MSI) to connect from an [Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql#:%7E:text=Managed%20Service%20Identities%20are%20automatically%20managed%20by%20Azure,to%20Azure%20SQL%20Database%20Enable%20Azure%20AD%20authentication), from an app hosted in [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#:%7E:text=Managed%20identities%20in%20App%20Service%20make%20your%20app,you%20built%20in%20one%20of%20the%20following%20tutorials%3A), or from an app hosted in [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity).

For AAD auth without using an MSI you can create an AAD [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-authenticate-service-principal-powershell) for the web app generate an access token for the Service Principal using a certificate or client secret, instead of getting the token using an MSI.

> without having to enter the SA creds in the connection string

You should never to that to begin with.  If using SQL Auth, provision a least-privileges SQL Login for the application to use.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i have setup the Service principal. But i struggling with the connection string and how to get it to connect using the service principal name

Comment: It doesn't go in the connection string.  You use the Service Principal to generate a access token, and set that to the SqlConnection.AccessToken property before opening the connection.  See eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql